# Unable to compile class for JSP: cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, tomcat, servlets

I am developing a Dynamic web project. Project is running well on local server but not on live. On live server it throws exception at the line I have used any java object:

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP:

```
    An error occurred at line: 7 in the jsp file: /groups.jsp
CollectionAppService cannot be resolved to a type
4: <%
5:  String json = "[]";
6:  try {
7:      CollectionAppService collectionAppService = new CollectionAppService();
8:      json = collectionAppService.getGroupsJson();
9:  } catch (Exception e) {
10:         e.printStackTrace();
```

Project run on local server but also have errors in error log for max class files:

Error:

```
Thu Sep 20 01:16:11 GMT+05:30 2012
File not found: /Users/sukhpal/Data/Workspaces/J2EE Workspace/CollectionApp/build/classes/com/mut/service/common/Constants.class.
```

Please help.(Tomcat is enabled on my live server).

Following is link of live server
http://mutmanager.com/webservice/groups.jsp

Answer (score 6):

It looks like you forgot to import your `CollectionAppService` in your JSP:

```
<%@ page import="your.package.CollectionAppService" %>
```

But, there is a major problem, you should not put Java code in your JSP. Instead, you should move your code to a class and invoke it from a Servlet or similar.

Main article for this:

- [How to avoid Java Code in JSP-Files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3177733/1065197)

Do not forget that learning is good, but also learning in the right way.

---

After read your question again, I see this Stacktrace line:

> File not found: /Users/sukhpal/Data/Workspaces/J2EE Workspace/CollectionApp/build/classes/com/mut/service/common/Constants.class

I guess that your problem is `Constant` class (and your `CollectionApp` as well) is inside a project B. You're using absolute path references from another project that contains these classes and maybe you're not uploading it.

Imagine this situation: You have a web project (project A) and you have some classes that already do a heavy and fancy job in another project (project B) that you reuse on most projects you work on. In your development environment, you have a reference from project A to project B, but then you only upload project A to your production environment. In this way, when project A wants to call a class from project B, it will never find it, and the exception is thrown.

The best solution:

- Create a jar from project B.
- In project A, remove all the references to project B.
- Add the jar into project A and set it in the Build Path.
- Upload your project A to production.

Comment: Thank you for replying. But I have imported the class files. Also I mentioned above it works fine on local tomcat server but problem is on live tomcat server. I have purchased shard hosting with tomcat and java.

Comment: If the class is imported, then the problem is that you deployed your application but missed that class. Make sure all your compiled classes are in WEB-INF/classes folder (in that folder you would see your packages as folders).

Comment: Thank you. Class is exist. This problem is for all jsp pages at the line where they are using java class. All servlets are working fine. Jsp files are unable to load any java class.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Check it and tell me if I'm wrong or if you don't understand something.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are missing import statement on top of the JSP

You need to import user defined classes using import

Example:

```
<%@ page import="yourpackage.CollectionAppService" %>
```